# Remove previous scenes from memory in Unity 3d

Tags: unity

I'm making a game in unity3d which I optimized as much as I can.

I've made different levels in each scene.

After a few scenes the game starts to lag on mobile devices. And works smoothly if application is restarted and game is continued from last scene .

How can I clear previously loaded scene in Unity3d or overcome the problem I mentioned above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when loading a scene, everything in the previous scene is **destroyed**.

However, some resources might remain loaded. Try use [Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets.html).

In order to prevent a GameObject from being destroyed when a new scene is loaded, you can call [DontDestroyOnLoad](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html). Make sure that your code doesn't abuse this functionality.

Comment: To add to this, Materials, Textures, and Meshes can cause memory leaks, if you're creating them from scratch or copying them (note that renderer.material returns a copy the first time it's used) and not manually Destroy()ing them when you're done. Better to fix this at the source than fall back on Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets when you can. Even without memory leaks though, it's possible that you're doing a lot of allocations & deallocations that are fragmenting memory and making the garbage collector work extra hard over time. Look for places where you can allocate a buffer/pool once and reuse